# Вывод заголовков колонок в результате запроса из pipelined функции в 19c

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, plsql, oracle19c

Имеется пакет, который прекрасно работает в 11g версии.
Но если пытаюсь использовать его в 19c версии, то он компилируется без ошибок, но вывод результата отличается.

Вот воспроизводимый пример:

```sql
create table tbl1 (id number, description varchar2 (50));  
/
create or replace package pkg1 is 
    cursor cur1 is 
        select id, description  
        from tbl1 
        where 1=2; 
    type curtype is table of cur1%rowtype;
    function func (n number) return curtype pipelined; 
end pkg1;
/
create or replace package body pkg1 is 
    function func (n number) return curtype pipelined as 
        tab curtype := curtype (); 
    begin 
        for i in 1..n loop tab.extend; 
            tab(i).id := i; 
            tab(i).description := 'test'||i; 
            pipe row (tab(i)); 
        end loop; 
    return; 
    end; 
end pkg1;
/
select * from table (pkg1.func (2));
```

Результат:

```
    ATTR_1 ATTR_2                                            
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1 test1                                             
         2 test2
```

Ожидал получить заголовки колонок как они определены в курсоре - `ID, DESCRIPTION`.
Но в 19c получаю - `ATTR_1, ATTR_2`.

Как можно изменить это поведение?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/60225275/6571020

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На портале [Спроси Тома](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=oracle-19c-database-issue-with-table-types-and-pipelining#followup-) [@ConnorMcDonald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7367293/connor-mcdonald) подтвердил, что имеет место баг в актуальной версии и необходимо обратится в техническую поддержку. Также воспроизводится в 18c.

---

Пока следует использовать вместо курсора базовую таблицу или представление для определения типа данных в выражении `%rowtype`. Например так:

```sql
create or replace package pkg1 is 
    cursor cur1 is 
        select id, description  
        from tbl1 
        where 1=2; 
    type curtype is table of tbl1%rowtype; --instead of cur1%rowtype;
    function func (n number) return curtype pipelined; 
end pkg1;
/
```

Всё остальное без изменений. Результат как ожидался:

```
        ID DESCRIPTION                                       
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1 test1                                             
         2 test2
```