# Как открыть курсор для вложенной таблицы с элементами %ROWTYPE?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Пробую так:

```
declare
    cursor cur0 is select no, dt from data123;
    type TempTabTyp0 is table of cur0%ROWTYPE index by pls_integer;
    temp_tab0 TempTabTyp0; 
    lrc sys_refcursor; 
begin
    open cur0;
    fetch cur0 bulk collect into temp_tab0;
    close cur0;
    for rec in 1 .. temp_tab0.count loop 
        temp_tab0(rec).no := 'new value' || temp_tab0(rec).no;
    end loop;  
    open lrc for select * from table (temp_tab0);
end;
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> Error report -
> ORA-06550: line 13, column 39:
> PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

Без последней строки всё работает.

Как тогда можно открыть `sys_refcursor` для вложенной таблицы `temp_tab0`?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How can i select data from table of %ROWTYPE to refcursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63984017) от участника [@Sergei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14311428/sergei)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/63984017

Answer (score 3):

Причина ошибки - объявленный в анонимном блоке тип данных неизвестен в SQL контексте.

Достаточно обернуть имеющийся код в пакет. Вот так:

```
create table data123 (no, dt) as
    select cast ('abc' as varchar2 (30)), date'2020-09-21' from dual
/
create or replace package pack1 as
    cursor cur0 is select no, dt from data123;
    type TempTabTyp0 is table of cur0%rowtype index by pls_integer;
    procedure getcur (rc out sys_refcursor);
end;
/
create or replace package body pack1 as
    procedure getcur (rc out sys_refcursor) is 
        temp_tab0 TempTabTyp0;
    begin
        open cur0;
        fetch cur0 bulk collect into temp_tab0;
        close cur0;
        for i in 1..temp_tab0.count loop 
            temp_tab0(i).no := 'new value '||temp_tab0(i).no;
        end loop;
        open rc for select * from table (temp_tab0);
    end;
end;
/
```

Запуск и результат:

```
var rc refcursor
exec pack1.getcur (:rc)

ATTR_1                         ATTR_2             
------------------------------ -------------------
new value abc                  2020-09-21 00:00:00
```

---

PS некорректные заголовки [обусловленны багом](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=oracle-19c-database-issue-with-table-types-and-pipelining#followup-), решение см. в [этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1085767).